# Take all digits from a string and present them in a list

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I was doing some Haskell exercises but can't solve the last one.

I need to **recursively** define functions that are already defined in the Data.Char module.

The last function I need to define is of this type:

```
nums :: String -> [Int]
```

Here is the (translated) question:

> Using functions from the Data.Char module, define recursively the following functions:
>
> (c) nums :: String -> [Int] which receives a string and outputs a list
> with the numerical digits that occur on that string, by the same order.

```
--This is my code

numbers :: String -> [Int]
numbers [] = []
numbers (l:ls) = if ord l >= 48 && ord l <= 57
                 then l : (numbers ls)
                 else (numbers ls)
```

I've been getting this error on the interpreter:

```
pratica3.hs:137:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Char'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `l'
    In the expression: l : (numbers ls)
    In the expression:
      if ord l >= 48 && ord l <= 57 then
          l : (numbers ls)
      else
          (numbers ls)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're only doing filtering, but `l` is still a `Char` when you cons it to `numbers ls`. You'll need to convert `l` to an `Int`.

Comment: You can compare `Char`s directly, e.g. `l >= '0' && l <= '9'`, there is no need to convert them to `Int` there. You instead have to convert them before you build your list of `Int`s. Also, your code will produce a list of one-digit numbers, only. E.g. it will never include 123, only 1,2,3. Is that intended?

Comment: Might be you want to break the string into `words` and convert those to numbers (`map`) by some implementation of `read`?

Comment: @chi that's exactly what I'm trying to do, maybe "numbers" wasn't the best name here, but yeah I need to extract the algarisms from a String.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I understand. How would you suggest I do that? I thought of doing then chr (ord  l) : (numbers ls) but wouldn't that be considered a character too? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

The solution is:

```
numbers :: String -> [Int]
numbers [] = []
numbers (l:ls) = if ord l >= 48 && ord l <= 57
    then (ord l - 48): (numbers ls)
    else (numbers ls)
```

This is correct.

Comment: This is not an adequate answer. I realise this is your question, but firstly, remove "thank you!" messages, and secondly, explain why and how this fixes the problem you had. Please edit it.

Comment: @AJFarmar  
First I'm sorry. Second I understand that I am speaking with people way more knowledgeable than me and that they probably know thousands of ways around solving this problem. I am saying this because I do not know another answer for my problem with my 4 hours total of classes and I really want to describe it more and make it "not misleading" but the best I can do is to translate the question. I did not understand Emacs User's answer, as much as I wanted to.

Comment: This is not an excuse for writing and posting an answer that goes against the answering guidelines. You have improved your answer, so I've now up-voted it, but keep in mind that I was not insulting you. I know full well you are inexperienced, but answers here must be written to a certain standard. Refer to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Typically, I'd expect `numbers "d 4432 424 23"` => `[4432, 424, 23]` but this gives `[4,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3]`. [How to extract all numbers from a string in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524010/how-to-extract-all-numbers-from-a-string-in-haskell) has code for the expected behavior.

Comment: @ggorlen I should have been more specific in my title, and the assignment uses a word that does not seem to exist in English. It was supposed to say "outputs a list with the **numerical digits** that occur on that string" so the current output is correct. Your expected output is an interesting related question, please do not delete it

Comment: "_Digits_ in a string" matches your interpretation, but I suspect many people (like myself, when I posted that comment half a year ago) will want "numbers in a string". I'm not deleting anything, just pointing future visitors to an alternate interpretation of this often-searched use case ("numbers in a string").

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a class problem, here are some hints. Use the function `words` to first break the string into individual elements, drop all non-numeric characters, then `read "elem":Int` for each element of your string and filter out those that return false. What's left will be `[Int]`.

The magic as is obvious is in the `read` function that takes a char representation of numbers and converts them to Int. If you have very large numbers, consider using `read "elem":Integer` variation.

Comment: @C.Rib, your solution is incomplete or your question is misleading. Fix one or the other.

Comment: Even after all these years I still stand by my solution. It could have been done differently, if I had more experience at the time, but it still is correct and the question is not misleading, your interpretation of it is at fault, especially if you did not get the question after reading the assignment question in the original post.